# Find a vector which is perpendicular to the implicit curve $(xy)^2 - 4 = 0$, at the point $(1,2)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function

What I did was:

1. Take the partial derivative of x and y obtaining [$2xy^2,2x^2y$] as the general gradient of my tangent line.
2. I plugged in $(1,2)$ to obtain the specific gradient of my tangent line, obtaining $[8,4]$.
3. We know that if the dot product of two vectors = 0, then these two vectors are perpendicular. So I solved for the perpendicular vectors and obtained: $[-4,8]$ or $[4,-8]$ as two specific vectors that are perpendicular to the implicit curve at $(1,2)$.

I am going to feel like a total idiot with tunnel vision but up until literally writing this post I have been trying to solve for the perpendicular vector to the line tangent to my implicit curve at the point $(1,2)$.

Would the vector perpendicular to the implicit curve of $(xy)^2 - 4 = 0$ at the point $(1,2)$ just be the specific gradient of my tangent line at the point $(1,2)$. So the answer to my question should just be $[8,4]$?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You have found the **normal** direction to your curve, not the tangent direction. But if $(r,s)$ is a normal direction then $(s,-r)$ is a tangent direction.

Comment: So the normal direction would be either the vectors [-4,8] or [8,-4] and the tangent direction would be [8,4], does this sound correct?

Comment: No, no, it's the other way round!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is $(xy)^2=4$, thus $xy=\pm2$, the union of two hyperbolas. Your point lies on the branch $xy=2$, so you’re asking for the normal direction to the graph of the function $y=2/x$ where $x=1$. Differentiating, we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=-2/x^2$, so the tangent at your point has slope $-2$, and the normal line has slope $1/2$, so a good normal vector would be $[2,1]$, agreeing with your final result.